# What scenarios would NativeOverlapped or System.Threading.Overlapped be useful in PFX IOTaskScheduler?

Tags: task-parallel-library, parallel-extensions, overlapped-io

I'm looking at the PFX team's [Parallel Extensions Extras DLL](https://nuget.org/packages/MSFT.ParallelExtensionsExtras/) and see an [IOTaskScheduler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/09/9990424.aspx) that uses NativeOverlapped, and System.Threading.Overlapped methods.

Since there isn't much documentation on when each extension is useful, it is up to me to read the source code and determine when I should use a given function.

When would I use the IOTaskScheduler, or the NativeOverlapped feature?

[(Direct link to source code)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-for-Parallel-b4b76364/sourcecode?fileId=44488&pathId=1961911776)
[(Documentation at bottom of this page)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ParExtSamples/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx)

Comment: My guess is that if you don't know when would you use them, then you don't need them.

Comment: @svick I didn't know I needed OOP or .NET until I got out of procedural programming and learned what an "object" was.  ;)  I'll keep learning stuff and hope I find something that I can use down the road.